# PyParsing - Parsing strings that must contain at least one occurrence of a symbol

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse strings using PyParsing and detect at parsing time if they contain at least one occurrence of a defined symbol (say ‘$’).

For example, the following string would be parsed:

```
"('a$x' & 'b') | $ | ('c' <-> $)"
```

But this one would not (and a parsing exception would be raised):

```
"('a$x' & 'b') | 'c'"
```

How can this be done?

My goal here is to build abstract syntax trees (ASTs) that must contain at least one occurrence of this special symbol '$'. For the moment, I consider '$' as a simple literal:

```
my_symbol = Literal('$')
my_symbol.setParseAction(lambda tokens: Symbol())
```

and I verify the "at least one occurrence" condition after parsing, i.e., once my AST is built (note that `Symbol()` is a class that represent '$' in my AST). However, I think that a detection at parsing time would be more efficient.

**EDIT:** I don't know if it may help but here is a simplified version of the grammar I would like to parse:

```
<a> ::= '$' | '~' <a> | <a> '&' <b> | <b> '&' <a> | <a> '|' <b> 
      | <b> '|' <a> | <a> '->' <b> | <b> '->' <a> | <a> '<->' <b> 
      | <b> '<->' <a> | '(' <a> ')'

<b> ::= 'True' | 'False' | <atom> | '~' <b> | <b> '&' <b> | <b> '|' <b> 
      | <b> '->' <b> | <b> '<->' <b> | '(' <b> ')'

<atom> is defined by any string surrounded by single quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of validation is not easy to implement in the grammar itself, so I usually do it in a parse-time callback, or `parse action`.  Here is an example, a simple parser looking for words composed of alphabetic letters.

```
alpha_word = Word(alphas)
```

With this test string, we can see that it will match upper and lower case words.

```
print alpha_word.searchString("abc DEF ghi Jkl")

[['abc'], ['DEF'], ['ghi'], ['Jkl']]
```

Let's say we want to reject words that are all upper case (but still accept words that are mixed or all lowercase).  This is actually kind of difficult to express in pure pyparsing grammar, so we define a validation callback to be called at parse time:

```
def reject_all_upper_case(src, locn, tokens):
    if tokens[0].upper() == tokens[0]:
        raise ParseException(src,locn,'reject words in all caps')
```

And then attach the parse action to the `alpha_word` expression:

```
alpha_word.setParseAction(reject_all_upper_case)
```

Now if we rerun the test:

```
print alpha_word.searchString("abc DEF ghi Jkl")

[['abc'], ['ghi'], ['Jkl']]
```

In your case, you would define a parse action for the overall expression, and then only accept it if you had a '$' symbol somewhere in the parse results.

**EDIT**

So it looks like `True & True`, `False | "lskdjf"`, and `$ -> True` are okay, but `$ -> $` should fail. I think I would start with just this simple parser:

```
term = Literal('True') | 'False' | '$' | quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
expr = infixNotation(term, 
            [
            ('~', 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
            (oneOf('-> <->'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
            ('&', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
            ('|', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
            ])
```

And then post-process the parse results to do the additional validation semantics of '$'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't see what you mean by "for the overall expression". Do you mean I should define a parse action for the input string?

Comment: You'll have to attach the parse action to the expression that spans all the places you will accept a '$'. Of course, you can't attach it to `my_symbol`, that will *always* report that it contains a '$' symbol. You have to go up the grammar - potentially all the way to the complete parser - depending on where you have defined '$' to be acceptable. If you want more specific help, you may have to post more of your parser.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I make recursive calls in my current parser. Therefore, the callback function is called several times during parsing, and I get "wrong" parsing errors. I edited my question to add the grammar I would like to parse. In your opinion, should I write 2 parsers (one for non-terminal 'a', and another for non-terminal 'b'), or only one could do the job (my choice for the moment)?